# javascript getter and setter within object property within class

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

As we know, getters and setters are basically functions that allow for computed properties while maintaining the simplicity of accessing them like properties instead of methods/functions.

It may or may not be relevant that I've particularly found this useful with the new private class members.

Example:

```
class A {
    #a;
    constructor() {
        this.#a = "something";
    }
    get a() {
        // do some stuff that a depends on a...
        // ... and then ultimately return it: 
        return this.#a;
    }
    set a(arg) {
        // do some stuff that depends on a or vice versa...
        // ... and then ultimately set a to something: 
        this.#a = something();
    }
}
```

Of course it looks like two "functions" but I access it as a property:

```
const aObj = new A();
console.log(aObj.a);  // runs the getter
aObj.a = "x"; // runs the setter
```

So now... I'm trying get that same functionality, but where `a` (and a bunch of other properties) are not always loose on the top level of the class, but some of them be properties within object definitions inside the class. Something like:

```
class B {
    #innerObjProp;
    constructor() {
        this.#innerObjProp = {};
        this.#innerObjProp.b = "b";
    }
    get this.#innerObjProp.b() {
        // do some stuff that b depends on...
        // ... and then ultimately return it: 
        return this.#innerObjProp.b;
    }
    set this.#innerObjProp.b(arg) {
        // do some stuff that depends on b or vice versa...
        // ... and then ultimately set b to something:
        this.#innerObjProp.b = something();
    }
}
```

To my knowledge (and according to my IDE) that `get` and `set` above is not correct syntax, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

*(`#innerObjProp` and `#a` are private in these examples, which is desired in my current case, but that's not key to the question. Presumably if there's a way to do this, it's the same for both private and public properties.)*

Can anyone tell me please if this is possible, and how?

Thanks in advance for help!

---

2 hours later, update. A couple of code corrections above.  Plus, feeling a need to clarify a couple of things based on questions in the comments:

TL;DR, short version: I'm looking for something that conceptually is:

```
this.#innerObjProp.(get b(){ 
    return ... ;
});
this.#innerObjProp.(get c(){ 
    return ... ;
});
```

I realize that's not correct syntax but I can't find anywhere that shows what it should be.

---

More detail. *Skip this if the above is clear enough:*

My node command line app is connected to an API that's streaming consistently updated data. I have access to 2 or 3 large API objects with everything I need in them, constantly being updated. At any moment I have the latest data but it's changing frequently (some more than 1/sec).  I don't need write access to any of it, only read. It absolutely needs to be organized differently for my app than it's being delivered to me or my code will be an organizational nightmare.

So my classes, some static some instantiated, are collections of read only properties, needing to be derived on the fly. I have a couple of classes that are doing almost nothing but rearranging it all and handing bits out to the rest of the app as needed.

It seems to me that a getter is a great option for each of these, each with the name my app would prefer, reading on the fly from the API object(s), making some adjustments (they're derived calculated properties) and delivering that result to whatever else in my app that asked for it.

Until I figure this out I'm just organizing all these properties at their classes' top levels, but I'd much prefer to group some of them together. That's where things like innerObjProp comes in.

Finally, I need to use some of the properties in a couple of the groups before I have access to all of them. Therefore, thanks to @Bergi below, `this.#innerObjProp = { get ...(), get...(), get...()}` works at first but I can't figure out the syntax for adding another getter to it later in the code like I can with an ordinary property eg. `this.#innerObjProp.c = ...`.

Comment: quick question... why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: "*`a = something();`*" - did you mean `this.#a = something();`?

Comment: "*Of course it's two "functions" but I can access it as if it were a property*" - no, it really is one property. An accessor property with a get and a set attribute - try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, "a")`.

Comment: would `get innerObjb() {return this.#innerObjProp.b}``set innerObjb(arg) {this.#innerObjProp.b = arg }` not work for you?

Comment: @Bergi, (1) good catch, yes I did mean this.#a.  That slipped through the proofreading.  I'll correct that in a moment.  (2) Yes, you're right about the property vs functions. I suppose I was talking more conceptually and trying to fend off any answers that might suggest "why don't you just use functions"?  ;-) I could probably have worded that better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to do is get that same functionality, but where the property is not loose on the top level of the class, but within an object property inside the class.

Then you need to create that object somewhere first. As you will want to have a separate object (with different property values) for each instance, create that instance-specific object in the constructor:

```
class B {
    #innerObjProp;
    constructor() {
        this.#innerObjProp = {};
    }
}
```

and then define your getters/setters in *that* object, not on the class level, with the usual ES5 syntax for getters/setters in object literals:

```
class B {
    #innerObjProp;
    constructor() {
        let b = "b"; // a local variable as a place to store the value
        this.#innerObjProp = {
            get b() {
                // do some stuff that b depends on...
                // ...
                // ... and then ultimately return it: 
                return b;
            },
            set b(arg) {
                // do some stuff that depends on b or vice versa...
                // ...
                // ... and then ultimately set b to something:
                b = something();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

Notice that this is a code smell. If your class has grown so large that you don't want to put some things at its "top level", something is wrong with your design, and you should consider splitting the class into multiple smaller classes.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense (& more desirable) to have innerObjProp's g/setters within it as you've done. I tried it but couldn't get the syntax right, so thanks for clearing that up.  So ok… 1. b needs to be part of #iOP. Is ```let b = …``` supposed to be *outside* of ```this#iOP = {…}```. 2. A distinction: ```this.#iOP = {…}``` sets #iOP all at once, but if I need to set bits of it in different places? If not g/setters, I can of course do ```this.#iOP.c = …``` (one at a time).  How do I add more g/setters 1 or 2 at a time in different places like we can with non-g/setter props? Thanks!

Comment: Good point about the code smell. This isn't really a qty/size thing. There's < 20 properties in this one, that all definitely go together as part of one thing. Say this was a datetime class I'm building, would I group two groups of three numbers each (date and time) if I could? Of course, I can -- objects.  Forgive me if I've misunderstood you: I'm pretty sure you're not saying a choice to bring g/setters into this will require me to break them out into 6 separate number properties at the top level, are you?

Comment: @DavidT You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to add getters/setters to an object afterwards. I don't see a reason to do that here, though. And yes, `let b` is supposed to go outside of the object literal.

Comment: @DavidT I'm saying that if you want to group them into subobjects, you should write three classes instead of one: `Date`, `Time`, and `DateTime`.

Comment: Hey again @Bergi.  You generously answer a lot of questions on this forum, including others of mine in the past, so thanks as always.  I can't seem to get the syntax right for Object.defineProperty() adding a g/setter to an object afterwards.  Though even if I could, I'd still ask this: could you update your answer to include how to do that.  I'd like to "accept" your answer, and would feel it's more complete if it included that.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(this.#innerObjProp, "b", {get() { …; return …; }, set(arg) { … });` should do. Maybe you want to ask a new question including your failed attempt?

Comment: And #Bergi Hmmm... I three separate classes makes sense in that example, so maybe not a good example? In the real case of what I'm doing (see my lengthy update), I'm not sure that's suitable here?  Idk, it seems overkill to split out into separate classes what is essentially already in separate classes (the API ones). A lot of the point of the class(es) I'm building is to group info from those others together,  but still have them somewhat organized.  Is there something I'm missing (or perhaps not explaining adequately) here?

Comment: Ok...  I think you're missing a closing "}" ...?    but yes, ok that's basically what I'm doing, and still getting errors, starting with "Unknown keyword or identifier. Did you mean 'object'?".  So, ok, I'll take your suggestion and post a new question, since it seems I'm hitting something new unrelated to this one. Thanks again!

Comment: -- and anyone else reading this:  Duh... writing up the new question, I figured it out... I was putting the `Object.defineProperty(...)` in the wrong place.  My brain was thinking I should put it in the same place as the getters -- in the top level of the class. But of course it's a statement not a declaration so it goes in the constructor or another function within.  At least that seems to be working now.